# FindControl returns NULL in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, findcontrol

I am trying to manipulate a `DropDownList`, which is in a field of a `GridView`, from code-behind in ASP.NET. I am doing this by adding the reference to a local DDL with the `FindControl` method. However, it doesn't seem to work, I have tried multiple approaches (`Load`, `Init` Events) but I always get a `NullReferenceException`.

Here is my code:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zuständige Führungskraft">
           <ItemTemplate>
           <!-- <%# Eval("ZustaendigeFuehrungskraft")%> -->
                <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" Enabled="false" runat="server" ID="ddwnFK" >

                </asp:DropDownList>
           </ItemTemplate>
           <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems="true" runat="server" ID="ddwnFK" >

                </asp:DropDownList>
           </EditItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

```
 protected void grdBenutzer_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Nachname, Vorname FROM Benutzer WHERE Benutzerart='Führungskraft' AND Archiviert != 1", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Load(dr);
            foreach (GridViewRow row in grdBenutzer.Rows)
            {
                DropDownList ddwnFK = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddwnFK");
                //if (ddwnFK == null)
                //    continue;

                ddwnFK.Items.Add("keine");

                foreach (DataRow dtRow in table.Rows)
                {
                    ddwnFK.Items.Add(dtRow["Nachname"].ToString() + ", " + dtRow["Vorname"].ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Comment about FindControl from MSDN: This method will find a control only if the control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls within controls.
Try to explore the tree of controls under row. May be, drop down is not a direct child.

Comment: thanks...what is the container in this case? gridview or single cell?

Comment: I think that most plausibly a single cell is a container.

Answer (score 0):

can you try access it as

```
DropDownList ddwnFK = (DropDownList)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
```

or see in the Quick watch what are the contents of row there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to find your drop down in every row of your grid (even header/footer row doesn't contain your drop down).

You can access the row being edited by using `GridViewEditEventArgs.NewEditIndex` property:

```
var row = grdBenutzer.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
var ddwnFK = (DropDownList)row.FindControl("ddwnFK");
```

Comment: thanks but this is something i already tried, it also gives me a NullReferenceException

Comment: @LeonidasFett: then I'd try something like `row.Cells[cellIndex].FindControl(...)`